# Keras get data in current iteration

Tags: machine-learning, keras

For example the batch-size is 128 and I got 1280 training samples. There are 10 iterations per epoch. How can I get the current training data of the current iteration? Which means that I want to get the data in the batch containing 128 training data. Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to feed the data into your model. Do you have the data in memory? Are you using a generator?

Comment: I have the data in memory.

Comment: As a numpy array? Then you can slice the array for the desired batch? eg, first batch will be `arr[:128]`

Comment: So you mean that I slice the data manually and feed to the keras model?

Comment: If you have the data in memory as a numpy array, you can just call `model.fit()` and pass the appropriate `batch_size`. See also the docs: https://keras.io/models/model/

Comment: Yeah, I know. Cause I want to do some other operations on the current batch. So I need to extract the data of current iteration. Maybe I should try tensorflow instead. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: In that case, you can try to write your own generator that yields the training data. You can include additional manipulations in the generator code. See here for an example https://github.com/sdcubber/keras_generator_boilerplate/blob/master/keras_generator.ipynb

Comment: That's it! Thanks for your help!